# MVC3 Cascade DropDownList pre-select values from database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've implemented a cascade dropdown list using jQuery and AJAX. This works fine on creating item, but I need to pre-select values from database when I edit existing item. I've tried to create a SelectList with pre-selected value from model, but that worked on the first dropdownlist only.

How can I make other lists showing item Area and Category values?

Here's my jQuery code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#ddlDeps").change(function() {
        var idArea = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON("/Admin/LoadAreasByDepartment", { id: idArea },
            function(depData) {
                var select = $("#ddlAreas");
                select.empty();
                select.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: 0,
                        text: "Выберите направление"
                    }));
                $.each(depData, function(index, itemData) {

                    select.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: itemData.Value,
                            text: itemData.Text
                        }));
                });
            });
    });


    $("#ddlAreas").change(function() {
        var idCategory = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON("/Admin/LoadCategoriesByArea", { id: idCategory },
            function(areaData) {
                var select = $("#ddlCategories");
                select.empty();
                select.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: 0,
                        text: "Выберите категорию"
                    }));
                $.each(areaData, function(index, itemData) {

                    select.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: itemData.Value,
                            text: itemData.Text
                        }));
                });
            });
    });
});
```

And this is my cascasing dropdownlist code:

```
   <p>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentId, new SelectList(Model.DataContainer.Departments, "Id", "Name"),
                            "Выберите отдел", new {id = "ddlDeps"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId)                                                    
</p>
<p>

    @{
        var areaSelectList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "DepartmentId", "Title", Model.AreaId);
        var categorySelectList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "AreaId", "Title", Model.CategoryId);
    }
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AreaId, areaSelectList,
                            "Выберите направление", new {id = "ddlAreas"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AreaId)             
</p>
<p>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, categorySelectList,
                            "Выберите категорию", new {id = "ddlCategories"})
</p>
```

Comment: You mean the last 2 drop downs are not populated when page loads?

Comment: Yes, they're still showing "Select ..." while I expected text specified by area or category id from model. I guess the problem is in  Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), but when I change this with my collection like in first list, the whole cascading stops working

Comment: So only one option `Select...` is present in both the dropdowns?

Comment: No, everything works fine except pre-selecting. If I replace Empty SelectListItem with my collection, 2nd and 3rd lists still showing collection items but changing values has no effect, looks like independent lists.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this in your code and try.

```
@{
        var areaSelectList = new SelectList(Model.DataContainer.Areas, "DepartmentId", "Title", Model.AreaId);
        var categorySelectList = new SelectList(Model.DataContainer.Categories, "AreaId", "Title", Model.CategoryId);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that was exactly what I've tried before. The Department field is correct, but Area and Category shows wrong values and I can select values not related to each other like Department is Flowers, Area is Tools and Category is New year. Actually, I have another idea:  maybe I should somehow set selected value in jQuery code, but I have no idea how can I pass value from db to client code.

Comment: Even I was thinking of doing that to set the selected value from the client side. You can render the areaId and categoryId in a js variable from the server side. On page load using these variables you can set the dropdown selected value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this trick, but I'm a novice in MVC and I don't know is this a good idea to create client variables on server side. Generally this problem is solved by setting selected value in Select list ctor like I did. but this don't work on cascading dropdowns.

Comment: Ideally it should be done on the server side itself but I dont know much of your model structure so cannot advice much. What I gave is a worst case solution.